# NHibernate - Best way to map to a secondary key

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to map a new domain model to a fixed-schema legacy database and am stuck on how to do a certain type of mapping.  Here's a distilation of my problem.

There are types of Workers.  For example an HourlyWorker and a SalariedWorker.

The data for an HourlyWorker is stored in the WORKERS table and the HOURLY_WORKERS table with a standard foreign key relation between the two of WORKERS.PK_WORKERS = HOURLY_WORKERS.FK_WORKERS.

The "Id" of the HourlyWorker from NHibernate's point of view is mapped to WORKERS.PK_WORKERS, which is as it should be.

So far so good.

Now suppose there is an object that applies only to hourly workers.

```
class Timesheet
  HourlyWorker Owner { get; private set; }
```

In the legacy database this maps to the TIMESHEETS table in a fairly straightforward manner but with one catch:  The foreign-key link to the owner is expressed not through a link to the WORKER table but via a link to the HOURLY_WORKER table.  In other words, the foreign key FK_HOURLY_WORKER is a unique identifier but is *not* pointing at the value that is in NHibernate's view the primary key.

I cannot simply change the Id HourlyWorker to map to the HOURLY_WORKER table because 70% of the database referencing houry workers uses the primary key from WORKER as the foreign key Id.

**What are my options for mapping this relationship?**

Something that might make this easier: the Owner property is read only - the Timesheet cannot have it's owner changed.  However, when an HourlyWorker is deleted, deletes should cascade to all of their Timesheets.

Finally, please don't respond with recommendations that I change the database.  I know.  If you want my client's phone number so that you can try to convince them that their schema is not the most perfect thing in existence then I can supply it.  I have been fighting this fight for months.  Also please don't respond that this indicates that the problem is managerial and not just NHibernate mappings.  I know that too.  For right now, I just want advice on how to solve the technical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the **property-ref** attribute of the many-to-one element:
[NHibernate docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

By the way, mapping to a legacy schema is hard - be prepared for some serious pain! On the plus side, you'll be an NHibernate expert by the time you come out on the other side.